# MySQL - Grouping with subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am having trouble with a subquery and some grouping.  The subquery is selecting from the whole table instead of just the individual groups...my code

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC(call_start) - TIME_TO_SEC(call_start)%(30*60)) AS intervals, 
       COUNT(*) AS OFFERED, 
       SUM(agent_duration) AS AGENT_SUM, 
       SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(dequeue_time, enqueue_time))) AS ANS_TIME_SUM, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT agent_username) AS UNIQUE_AGENTS, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM call_detail
        WHERE TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(dequeue_time, enqueue_time)) < 40) AS SLA, 
       SUM(queue_duration) AS TOTAL_QUEUE_TIME 
FROM call_detail
WHERE DATE(call_start) = CURDATE()
GROUP BY intervals
```

My goal is to have that subquery just return the number of records where that TIMEDIFF result is less than 40 within that particular interval

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need a subquery for this.  Just do conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC(call_start) - TIME_TO_SEC(call_start)%(30*60)) AS intervals, 
       COUNT(*) AS OFFERED, 
       SUM(agent_duration) AS AGENT_SUM, 
       SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(dequeue_time, enqueue_time))) AS ANS_TIME_SUM, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT agent_username) AS UNIQUE_AGENTS, 
       sum(case when TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(dequeue_time, enqueue_time)) < 40 then 1 else 0 end) as SLA,
       SUM(queue_duration) AS TOTAL_QUEUE_TIME 
FROM call_detail
WHERE DATE(call_start) = CURDATE()
GROUP BY intervals;
```

You would use the subquery to get a total over *all* record, not the ones affected by the `where` clause or the `group by`.

Comment: +1 I was going to post an answer that joins with a subquery that's grouped, and another solution using a correlated subquery, but I like this better.

Comment: Thanks guys...I'll check this out and post my results

Comment: Yes.  That did it.  Really appreciate the quick response.

Comment: PS...is it fair to post a new question regarding the same query here? Or should I start a new question?  Thanks again.

Comment: @user2263663 . . . If it is a minor tweak, then you can ask the question.  If it really is different, then ask another question.  There are "duplicate question hawks" out there who seem very sensitive to similar questions by the same poster.

Comment: Thanks...I think I will tinker with it a bit first then ask a new question if I can't figure it out.  I am adding to the query used in this question.